# How do I connect a Backbone router with React components?

Tags: backbone.js, reactjs, backbone-routing

I'm in the early stages of planning a web app built around consuming a content-management API. I have really taken a liking to Backbone.js after finding its ability to easily parse collections and models from REST end points.

I would like to have a full client-side routing solution with pretty URL's via pushState and browser history. Backbone has a router but I am not sure how to structure my React views and Backbone logic to make this all happen. Any pointers?

Also limelights mentioned React Router. Is this a better way to go while still interfacing with Backbone models, collections, and events?

Comment: If you're not locked into using Backbone then look at React Router for great compatibility.

Comment: I'm not locked into using Backbone, but after some preliminary research, I really like its control over events, models, and collections. I'm wondering how to best combine this layer with React views. However, if it makes sense, I'll gladly use React Router and skip the Backbone router. Adding that to my question.